# How to specify the elements in bullet points while using <s:iterator>?

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I am using an s:iterator element in my jsp page, whose value is set from a **struts action class**. How do I get the elements to come in bullet points?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style="color:graytext;">
<s:iterator value="getKfList()" var="a">
            <s:property value="a" /><br>
        </s:iterator>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. So simple. Sorry for the simple question. Nevertheless, posting solution for others' reference.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="color:graytext;">
            <s:iterator value="getKfList()" var="a">
                       <li> <s:property value="a" /> </li>
                    </s:iterator>

            </div>
```

Comment: This is pretty suspicious HTML, though, not really valid.